# Is it ok to prevent users from exporting their data

Tags: data-ownership, encryption, competition

Am I allowed to encrypt customers data residing on their servers, preventing them   from exporting the data to a competition without my help. I need it to make sure the customer doesn't change services before paying off the bill.

I'm providing them with the software to access data, the user is creating the data using my software, which saves it on the customers servers.

Question is if I'm allowed to save the data in a way only my software should be able to read it, with no option to export. the data is saved in a sql server database which gives the option to encrypt the data with a secret key, customer has no way of exporting that data without the key.

I guess the customer owns the data, and I'm not looking to take it away from them, Just need to block them from changing providers without contacting me first... once the customer is already hooked up with another similar software its very difficult for me to get the money out, even with the contract. On the other hand, if they need my help changing provider, I could get the money easily.

Customers don't sign long contracts when purchasing the software.. so there's no real agreement between us about the data etc.

Comment: How is your relationship with them structured? Is it based on a contract? Under what means did they grant you access to their servers? Who owns the data? Why are you not looking at filing a lien to ensure payment?

Comment: Editing the question to include the details you've added in the comments would be helpful. The other useful bit of information would be to determine if you have a license under which they are using the software and if that license includes a clause about which jurisdictions laws will govern the license. Without that information this would feel more like an ethics question than a legal question.

Comment: This is a very, very dangerous game to play. I would _not_ do this without talking to a lawyer first. If you cause a customer damage through this action, they could sue you for damages which could be very expensive.

Comment: Thanks for that comment, I figured it could possibly be a legal problem  that's why I asked before.

Comment: @JasonAller Edit done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I believe that this is legal in most places, provided your agreements don't say anything to the contrary, and provided that the users can still view the information.

Comment: "Illegal"? I have not looked up the case law but my guess is the law frowns upon this type of thing proposed here.

Comment: Nope, I believe its legal - You must live in a very enlightened country - one far away from American Corporates clutches !  Google  the term"Proprietary Format" and you will see it is sadly common.

Comment: I would cite Restat 2d of Torts, § 766B to the contrary.

Comment: @user3344003 - If my Google-Foo suffices, 766B is "Tortious interference with prospective contractual relations" - The OP has specifically said he is not trying to prevent the data from being moved - just that he wants to get paid first - that does not sound like Tortious Interference to me.

Comment: He's interfering with someone trying to establish a contractual relationship with someone else.

Comment: Also, check the case history of that restatement. There is a very interesting one about blocking someone until they pay their bill.

Comment: I believe this is no longer the case thanks to GDPR